# Unity 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm trying to build an android aplication in Unity version 2021.3.17f1 using the google cardboard plugin 1.16.0 and at the time to build and run i get this error

WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

The project dosen't contain anything else than the helloCardboard escene.

I've tried with newer versions of cardboard plugin and unity but i still got the same error

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.